# how to retrieve and create nested object from an spring mvc form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i am learning spring mvc right now and I am facing with a question. I have two objects Country and Capital. What I am trying to accomplish is when I created an new country in the jsp I would like to create an new capital along with it (country name , population, and capital name will be enter by user). I am not sure how to retrieve the Capital object and how to pass it to my controllers. Please explain. Thanks!!

Country.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COUNTRY")
public class Country{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name="countryName")
    String countryName; 

    @Column(name="population")
    long population;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="capitalId")
    Capital capital; 

    public Country() {
        super();
    }
    public Country(int i, String countryName,long population) {
        super();
        this.id = i;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.population=population;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
    public long getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    public void setPopulation(long population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
    public Capital getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
    public void setCapital(Capital capital) {
        this.capital = capital;
    }   
}
```

Capital.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAPITAL")
public class Capital {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="capitalName")
    private String capitalname;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCapitalname() {
        return capitalname;
    }
    public void setCapitalname(String capitalname) {
        this.capitalname = capitalname;
    }
}
```

countryDetails.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="country" action="/SpringMVCHibernateCRUDExample/addCountry">
<table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Add Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <form:hidden path="id" />
          <td><form:label path="countryName">Country Name:</form:label></td>
          <td><form:input path="countryName" size="30" maxlength="30"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><form:label path="population">Population:</form:label></td>
          <td><form:input path="population" size="30" maxlength="30"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="capital">Capital</form:label></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                class="blue-button" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form:form>
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: You can do something like `<form:input path="capital.capitalname"/>`

Comment: @RossiRobinsion so I don't need to set another model attribute for Capital class in the form?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion worked. Thanks a lot.